# TFS warehouse custom adapter

Tags: tfs, tfs-reports, tfs-analysis

We are trying to develop custom adapters for the TFS warehouse in TFS 2018. We have created what we suppose (because of the lack of documentation) to be a basic adapter for Git repositories.

We have a class named `GitWarehouseAdapter` inheriting from `WarehouseAdapter` and one named `GitRepositoryWarehouseSyncExtension` from `WarehouseSyncJobExtension<GitWarehouseAdapter>`.
The `GitRepositoryWarehouseSyncExtension` is only declared, there are no custom members. Are there any members that I should override?

I have tried putting the dll in the plugin folder of either the job scheduler or the web services. I was never picked up and run.

My question in fact is how do I register a custom TFS adapter in the system?

Comment: Did you restart the app tier after dropping in the DLL?

Comment: Yes I did, but it didn't change anything

Comment: Where did you put the dlls? Did you try to reset IIS? Please check the event log in Event Viewer, to see if there is any useful information. Also, check [this blog](http://zogamorph.blogspot.sg/2008/07/how-i-built-team-foundation-server.html) to see whether it helps you.

Comment: I tried to put it in the plugin subfolder for both the Web Services and the Job Scheduler folders

Comment: Have you checked event log? Is there any useful message?

Comment: No nothing in there, I checked the _oi page both the logs and jobs

Comment: I mean event log in Event Viewer on your TFS server machine.

Comment: I checked that as well, nothing